# Multiple Selectboxes focuses first select box

Tags: javascript, firefox

I've got three selectboxes in a fieldset.
Everything worked fine but after the new firefox update there's a problem.

When I click on the second or third selectbox it closes the dropdown and focuses the first selectbox. I have already disabled js and in the css there's only a border styling on focused element.

Any ideas?

```
<fieldset><div><label>Geburtsdatum:
              <input type="hidden" value="" id="birthDate" name="lottery.birthDate">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <select id="bDay" name="bDay">
                 </select>
              <select id="bMonth" name="bMonth">
                 </select>
              <select id="bYear" name="bYear">
                 </select>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </label></div></fieldset>
```

I've deleted the optionlists.

Got any Idea? 
This bug is only the latest firefox version.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move closing label tag after Geburtsdatum:

```
<fieldset><div><label>Geburtsdatum:</label>
                                      ^^
              <input type="hidden" value="" id="birthDate" name="lottery.birthDate">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <select id="bDay" name="bDay">
                 </select>
              <select id="bMonth" name="bMonth">
                 </select>
              <select id="bYear" name="bYear">
                 </select>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
           </div></fieldset>
```